# How to check whether a TIFF file truly has 16 bit depth

Tags: image-processing, imagemagick

Assume I convert an 8-bit TIFF image to 16-bit with the following ImageMagick command:

```
$ convert 8bit-image.tif -depth 16 16bit-image.tif
```

The result is a file that is detected by other programs as a file with 16-bit depth:

```
$ identify 16bit-image.tif
16bit-image.tif TIFF 740x573 740x573+0+0 16-bit sRGB 376950B 0.000u 0:00.000
```

Naturally, this file does not have "true" 16 bit, since it's an 8 bit file which has simply been marked as 16 bit. It hasn't got the subtle nuances one would expect from true 16 bit. How can I distinguish a true 16 bit image from one that just "pretends"?

Best,

Bela

Answer (score 1):

When you have an 8-bit image, the pixel values range from 0 to 255. For a 16-bit image, the pixel range is from 0 to 65535. So you can express more nuances in 16 bit than you can in 8 bit.

Usually, when you have a 16-bit imager in a camera, it is able to capture these nuances and map them to the full 16 bit range. An 8 bit imager will be limited to a smaller range, so when taking the picture, some information is lost compared to the 16 bit imager.

Now when you start out with an 8 bit image, that information is already lost, so converting to 16 bit will not give you greater nuance, because ImageMagick cannot invent information where there is none.

What image processing tools usually do is to fill copy the pixel values of your 8 bit image into the 16 bit image, so your 16 bit image will still contain only values in the range of [0,255]. If this is the case in your example, you can check whether the brightest pixel of your 16 bit image is greater than 255. If it is, you can assume that it is a native 16 bit image. If it isn't, it's *likely* that it was converted from 8 bit.

However, there is not a guarantee that the 16 bit image was really converted from 8 bit, as it could simply be a very dark native 16 bit image that only uses the darkest pixels from the 8 bit range by chance.

**Edit:** It is possible that someone converts the 8-bit image to 16 bit using the full 16 bit range. This could mean that a pixel of value 0 might remain at 0, a pixel at 255 might now be at 65535 and all values inbetween will be evenly distributed to the 16 bit range.

However, since no new information can be invented, there will be gaps in the pixel values used, e.g. you might have pixels of value 0, 255, 510 and so on, but values in between do not occur.

Depeding on the algorithm used for stretching the pixel range, these specific values may differ, but you would be able to spot a conversion like that by looking at the image' histogram: [image: image histogram 8 to 16 bit]

It will have a distinctive comb-like structure (image taken from http://www.northlight-images.co.uk/digital-black-and-white-working-in-16-bit/)

So depending on how the conversion from 8 to 16 bit is executed, finding out whether it is a native image or not may be a bit more complicated and even then it can not be guaranteed to robustly determine whether the image was actually converted or not.

Comment: Makes sense to me, thanks for the idea with the histogram!